# Can't figure out how to fix Google Search Console mobile friendly errors

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I have a Wordpress page using the HitMag theme (https://wordpress.org/themes/hitmag/).

After checking the Google Search Console I got some erros and am not able to fix them.

I attached the screenshot from Google.

Errors:

- Text too small
  (on the screenshot the text looks small but on all devices that I used for testing the text looks good and making it bigger would not look good)
- Content wider the screen
  (I can't see where this happens, the theme is completely responsive)
- Clickable elements to close
  (I also can'T find which links they are talking about).

It looks like there errors only apply on one page, whereas all others (using the same theme) are valid:

[image]

https://que-tedio.com.br/10-ideas-para-quem-tem-nada-para-fazer/

Any ideas on how to fix this are appreciated.

This is the screenshot generated by Google:

[image]

Comment: When you scroll down to the comment section, there are a few comments that extend beyond the screen size. This might explain at least one of the errors.

Comment: You have multiple problems.  Please post about each separately.